# reset typescript singleton instance in each unit test

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jestjs

I have a typescript singleton class like so:

```js
export default class MySingleton {
private constructor({
    prop1,
    prop2,
    ...
  }: MySingletonConfig) {
    
    this.prop1 = prop1 ?? 'defaultProp1';
    this.prop2 = prop2;
    this.prop3 = prop3 ?? 'defaultProp3';

    /* ... some instruction ... */

    MySingleton.instance = this;
  }

  static getInstance(params?: Configuration): MySingleton {
    if (!this.instance && !params) {
      throw MySingleton.instantiationError;
    }

    if (!this.instance) {
      new MySingleton(params);

      return this.instance;
    }

    return this.instance;
  }
}
```

When I want to unit test it using jest, like so:

```js
describe('getInstance()', () => {
    test('it should return the same instance every time', () => {
      const params = {
       /* ... all the params ... */
      };

     
      const mySingleton = MySingleton.getInstance(params);

      expect(MySingleton.getInstance()).toEqual(mySingleton);
    });
    test('it should return the instance with the default value', () => {
      const params = {
       /* ... ONLY THE REQUIRED PARAMS ... */
      };
     
      const mySingleton = MySingleton.getInstance(params);

      expect(mySingleton.prop1).toEqual('defaultProp1');
      expect(mySingleton.prop3).toEqual('defaultProp3');
    });
  });
```

This is failing, because we share the same instance between the  2 tests (as the singleton pattern work), therefore the second instantiation is useless.

Is there a way to reset/destroy the previous instantiation in order to properly check if those default values are properly setted with the second intantiation?

Comment: Hold on a second.  What does the tests sharing the same singleton have anything to do with the singleton having or not having the default values?  If you don't change their values, then they will start off with whatever their defaults are.  Edit: to clarify, if your tests that checks for default values happens before any other test that modifies them, then they will have the default values.

Comment: Can you access the MySingleton.instance field from the tests? If so, you could set that to null at the start of every test.

@Taplar He is trying to test the getInstance function. However if there is an instance, the behavior changes so he can't verify this properly.

Comment: @chingucoding I understand that.  What I'm saying is, if the value are not changed, they will be the defaults.  So if the describe for the `getInstance` method had a `beforeAll` that made a call to the getInstance to create the default instance, then both the "same instance" test and the "default values" tests could both use the same thing and work.  The only complication with that is if jest/jasmine is setup to run the specs in a random order.

Comment: @Taplar yes, but then all my other test would only be using the first instantiation (i.e: the one with default value) and the branches where we use the provided parameters are covered by the unit test :|

Comment: @chingucoding indeed that could do the trick, the thing is I setted the instance as a private field. Myabe thats what i'm doing wrong and should set it to public ?

Comment: I'm not intimately familiar with typescript.  Is there a way to make the instance 'protected'?  Such that, you could write a `TestMySingleton` class that extends the `MySingleton` class, that has a method that destroys the instance?

Comment: If what values are not changed? When one of the tests succeeds, the instance property of MySingleton is set, the next test will not change the instance then since you did not clear the instance. The question is about how to reset that instance, so how to implement the beforeAll

Comment: @Taplar yes this is also possible in typescript, it could also be a solution !

Comment: Unless you have problems with other modules depending on this module, you can just reimport it for different tests, e.g. with jest.isolateModules. FWIW singleton class is commonly an antipattern in JS/TS as single instance can be achieved with JS modules alone without enforcing a class to be a singleton or needing a class at all.

Comment: @EstusFlask i'm interrested on how to achieve this without using a class, when i need to pass arguments as config at least once. I couldn't think of another way to do so :|

Comment: Usually it's `function createMySingleton(config){` in one module and `export default createMySingleton(config)` in another one, the latter is evaluated only once and all modules that import it get the same instance. It's unknown why there's a possibility that it can be instantiated in different places with different params in your case but most times a config is known at this time.

Comment: And any way, static-only classes aren't legit in JS, they come languages that don't have other structs, it's `export let mySingleton = { getInstance: (config) => mySingleton._instance || (mySingleton._instance = ...) }` if you need to access an instance for testing purposes or else, or `let instance; export let getInstance = (config) => instance || (instance = ...)` if you don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why you couldn't do:

```
MySingleton.instance = null;
const mySingleton = MySingleton.getInstance(params);
```

Comment: I made the instance private, maybe that's my mistake ? 
I wanted that the only way to get the instance would be by using the `getInstance()` method

Comment: You can keep it private, that aspect is only enforced by the compiler, so you can always do something like `let tmp: any = MySingleton;  tmp.instance = null` in your tests

Comment: A way to do this in TS is `MySingleton['instance'] = null`.

Comment: Estus Flask solution worked for me! Cool.

Comment: I don't agree with this answer, in a good implementation of singleton the instance property should be private, so you couldn't do that!

Answer (score 2):

Ideally the `istance` property should be [really private](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields), but nobody prevents you from adding a `reset()` method on your class.
It is not particularly neat, as it would basically be for testing purposes only, but at least it would be more close to the canonical implementation of the singleton pattern.

That being said, I would carefully consider if using a singleton is a good idea. It might create a lot of headaches when unit testing your code.
Basically, the same problem you have here could present itself elsewhere when you try to test some code that makes use of your singleton.

Comment: thanks for your response ! 
I thought about the reset (/destroy) function, and for the exact reason you stated i was skeptical about implementing it

As for using the singleton in other unit test, i would simply mock it as it's not useful to test it in another test :) 

For more insight, we're trying to make a library for a payment provider therefore the configuration should not change after the first implementation. That's the reason why I made use of the singleton pattern

Comment: I see. Well, honestly, rather than implementing it as a singleton, I would just leave to the client code the responsibility to instantiate the class once and pass it around as needed (either as a global variable, or using some other method depending on the framework they use).

Comment: mmmh I see, I wanted to avoid that for us to use (as we're the main user for now). The idea behing the singleton usage, was set it up at the start of the application and never have to worry about it later on, and just grab the instance when needed. Thanks for your response, comment and insight ! :)

Comment: Not at all :) Anyway, that would also work for a global/shared variable (whatever you want to call it).

Comment: Be careful not to create a hard dependency, you if do something like

`function pay() {
  const paymentLib = MyPaymentLib.getIntance();
  paymentLib.pay();
}`

I would rather inject the dependency

`function pay(paymentLib = window.myPaymentLib) { // or wherever your variable is coming from
  paymentLib.pay();
}`

That's just my two cents, but of course, I lack knowledge of the full picture.

Answer (score 0):

**I have created a singleton class with the following reset methods and its working properly:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class SingletonDemo {
  private static _instance: SingletonDemo;

  public static getInstance() {
    return this._instance || (this._instance = new this());
  }

  public static resetInstance() {
    this._instance = null;
  }

}
```